# Why Hibernate's ManyToOne with mappedBy it's doing joins?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

I have the follow mapped entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "survey")
public class Survey implements Serializable {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "survey", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "question_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Question implements Serializable {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_survey", nullable = false, updatable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_question_survey"))
  private Survey survey;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SINGLE_CHOICE")
public class SingleChoiceQuestion extends Question {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", fetch = EAGER)
  private List<QuestionChoice> choices = new ArrayList<QuestionChoice>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "question_choice")
public class QuestionChoice implements Serializable {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_question", nullable = false, updatable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_question_choice_question"))
  private Question question;
}
```

When i call XXXX.getSurvey().getQuestions(), hibernate makes two joins on this query, one to retrieve the questions since the fetch is EAGER and another to retrieve the questions choices since the fetch of "choices" is EAGER too. XXXX.getSurvey().getQuestions() should return only eight questions, however i'ts returing 36 questions because exists 36 choices.

Why hibernate has this behavior ? Why it's not separating only the 8 questions ?

Comment: Please add QuestionChoice class to your question

Comment: I suppose field question belongs to QuestionChoice, it is correct ?

Comment: Sorry guys!
Ok, i think i found the answer. From what i searched, Hibernate doesn't support more than one EAGER fetch on the same query.
Survey retrieves questions and questions retrieves questions choices at the same query. So, Hibernate do joins to retrieve everything.

Comment: Putting the annotation @LazyCollection with FALSE value, hibernate breaks into a lot of queries.  

Query 1: Query survey where survey.id = Question.survey.id  
Query N: For each question hibernate queries for all question choice

Comment: I think that FetchType.Select on the list of questions would also solve the problem.